Use Same Access Token provided by External API till it expires, used by multiple SpringBoot (client) microservices
I need to design a project, where the springboot based application has multiple microservices making use of Resources (Multiple APIs) hosted at an External API provider.
The API Provider uses OAuth2.0 client credentials based Authentication & Authorization. For Authorization access token is generated through which APIs can be accessed. They also have a policy to retain the same token till 55 mins.
and based on this the solution needs to be derived. Test code is done based on the draft design till now.
Challenge faced:
How and where to store the generated token to be used in the consequent requests from any of our Microservices.
Draft Solution:

I have thought of using a Hashmap and store the token till 55 mins/expired. The logic to generate a fresh token would be based on the validation to check the expired time/remaining time of the token that is already stored in the Hashmap. If within 55 mins, pick from the Hashmap otherwise get a fresh token.

The challenge I am facing with this approach is that, the Spring Component I had created to handle steps prior to API call is passing a fresh instance of Bean and thus have a fresh instance of Hashmap everytime.
So the reuse of the token is failing and the external api provider is generating a fresh token for every API call.
Please advice / suggest the ways to handle and maintain the Bean having the token state, across sessions/microservices/consequent calls.
Assumption: Default bean type is always Singleton.So if the Bean is configured as Component, shouldnt it pass the same bean instance for every request?
Thanks.

storing a token in a map, in my opinion, is not the best solution, if you run several instances of the application you will encounter an extensibility problem, to solve this problem you need more input data, some store the token on the client side, which simplifies the process, some use external storage.
But if you like your solution, make it static ConcurrentHashMap in utilClass
